# How to extract keypoints from BodyPix model in React?

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, bodypix

I need help on this matter. I am trying to extract the keypoints from BodyPix to be saved in a JSON file. I can see the keypoints in the console whenever I inspect it from the browser. I also want to save the keypoints into an array or a variable maybe so that I can use it throughout the code. Thank you very much. Here's the code:

```
function App() {
  const bodyPixProperties = {
    architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
    outputStride: 16,
    multiplier: 0.75,
    quantBytes: 4
  };

  const runBodysegment = async () => {
    const net = await bodyPix.load(bodyPixProperties);
    console.log("BodyPix model loaded.");
    //  Loop and detect hands
    setInterval(() => {
      detect(net);
    }, 100);
  };

  const detect = async (net) => {
    // Check data is available
    if (
      ...

      const person = await net.segmentPersonParts(video, {
        flipHorizontal: false,
        internalResolution: 'medium',
        segmentationThreshold: 0.7
      });


      console.log(person);

      // const coloredPartImage = bodyPix.toMask(person);
      const coloredPartImage = bodyPix.toColoredPartMask(person);
      const opacity = 0.7;
      const flipHorizontal = false;
      const maskBlurAmount = 0;
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;

      bodyPix.drawMask(
        canvas,
        video,
        coloredPartImage,
        opacity,
        maskBlurAmount,
        flipHorizontal
      );
    }
  };
  runBodysegment();
```